# Cap or reset a php generated file

Tags: php

I have this php script which counts users online by saving IP address & access time into a separate file:

```
<?PHP
$file = "users.ini";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$time = time();
$content = @file_get_contents($file);
$new_content = $ip." = ".$time;
$content .= $new_content."\r\n";
@file_put_contents($file,$content);

$users = @parse_ini_file($file);
$count = 0;
foreach($users as $ip=>$time){
    if($time >= time() - 300){ // past 3 minutes
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
?>
```

Problem is, due to having lots of visitors, the "users.ini" file just keeps growing and at a certain point the script crashes because of this. 
Question is, how can I "reset" the "users.ini" file somehow? I don't need all that data piling up there, just for the last 2 minutes.
Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you.

PS: as a temporary measure, I've setup a cronjob to delete the file every 10 minutes. But I think there should be a more elegant fix for this.

Comment: Use a real database. Have a datetime column. Delete from table where datetime is less than now minus x minutes.

Comment: Also 300 seconds is 5 minutes, not 3. And calling `time()` once for every user in the ini file is rather inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
$file = "users.ini";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$time = time();
$content = @file_get_contents($file);
$new_content = $ip." = ".$time;
$content .= $new_content."\r\n";
@file_put_contents($file,$content);

$users = @parse_ini_file($file);
$count = 0;
$active_users ="";
foreach($users as $ip=>$time){
    if($time >= time() - 300){ // past 3 minutes
        $count++;

        // add active users to the files only
        $active_users = $ip." = ".$time;
        @file_put_contents($file,$active_users);

    }
}
echo $count;
?>
```

This one should help